# Robot Framework show error when my directory has Chinese

Tags: python, robotframework

Robot Framework show error when my directory has Chinese

My environment is as below:

- pywin32 (220)
- robotframework (3.0.2)
- robotframework-archivelibrary (0.3.2)
- robotframework-archivelibrary
  (0.3.2)
- robotframework-databaselibrary (0.8.1)
- robotframework-ftplibrary (1.3)
- robotframework-ride (1.5.2.1)
- robotframework-selenium2library (1.8.0)
- robotframework-sshlibrary(2.1.3)
- selenium (3.0.2)

[image]

[image]

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\testrunnerplugin.py", line 370, in OnTimer
>       self._test_runner.get_output_and_errors(self.get_current_profile())
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\testrunner.py", line 250, in get_output_and_errors
>       stdout, stderr, returncode = self._process.get_output(), \
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\testrunner.py", line 305, in get_output
>       return self._output_stream.pop()
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\testrunner.py", line 400, in pop
>       return result.decode('UTF-8')
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
>       return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 84: invalid start byte
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\testrunnerplugin.py", line 370, in OnTimer
>       self._test_runner.get_output_and_errors(self.get_current_profile())
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\testrunner.py", line 250, in get_output_and_errors
>       stdout, stderr, returncode = self._process.get_output(), \
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\testrunner.py", line 305, in get_output
>       return self._output_stream.pop()
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\testrunner.py", line 400, in pop
>       return result.decode('UTF-8')
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
>       return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 36: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your path is UTF8 and not something different like UTF16? You could check using `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`

Comment: the value of sys.getfilesystemencoding() is mbcs, how to change the filesystemenconding?

Comment: You could use Windows command "chcp".
For example in my case I use "chcp 1252".

Comment: in 'chcp 1252', what does 1252 mean?

Comment: I can not change the file system encoding to utf-8 on windows, do you have any solution about it?

Comment: @AlexBruce in 'chcp 1252' the number refers to the new code page which is used to correctly interpret the characters.  For more information please see the Wikipedia article here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#:~:text=Windows%2D1252%20or%20CP%2D1252,Spanish%2C%20French%2C%20and%20German.